# Closest() only first element JS

Tags: javascript

The problem is that the block contains several levels of spoilers, the spoiler is inside the spoiler, so I only need the first match of closest().

For example:

```
let drop_toggle = (e) => {
  clearTimeout(timer);

  const dropdown = e.target.closest(".js-drop-down");

  if(dropdown.classList.contains("js-drop-down_open")) {
    dropdown.classList.remove("js-drop-down_open");
  } else {
    if(document.querySelector(".js-drop-down_open")) document.querySelectorAll(".js-drop-down_open").forEach(el => el.classList.remove("js-drop-down_open"));
    dropdown.classList.add("js-drop-down_open");
  }

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

As you see .js-drop-down has 2 levels inside.

```
headline__userscope.js-drop-down

        .headline__userscope-dropgroup

      
            .lang-block.js-drop-down
              button.lang-block__open.js-drop-down__open
                img(src="img/ru.svg", alt="")
                i.i.i-angle
              .lang-block__dropdown.js-drop-down__dropdown
                .lang-block__wrap


            .user-informer
              button.user-informer__main.js-drop-down__open
              .user-informer__dropdown.js-drop-down__dropdown
                .user-informer__wrap
```

Comment: Closest, it works that for each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. What issue are you facing?

Comment: This `if(document.querySelector(".js-drop-down_open"))` is unnecessary. If there's no matching element, then the `NodeList` from `.querySelectorAll()` will be empty and the `.forEach()` won't do anything.